# Why does Python output a string and a unicode of the same value differently?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using Python 2.6.5 and when I run the following in the Python shell, I get:

```
>>> print u'Andr\xc3\xa9'
AndrÃ©
>>> print 'Andr\xc3\xa9'
André
>>>
```

What's the explanation for the above?  Given u'Andr\xc3\xa9', how can I display the above value properly in an html page so that it shows André instead of AndrÃ©?

Comment: Not sure why but I noticed this interesting result:

    >>> u'\xc3\xa9' == '\xc3\xa9'
    __main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
    False

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`'\xc3\xa9'` is the UTF-8 encoding of the unicode character `u'\u00e9'` (which can also be specified as `u'\xe9'`). So you can use `u'Andr\u00e9'` or `u'Andr\xe9'`.

You can convert from one to the other:

```
>>> 'Andr\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
u'Andr\xe9'
>>> u'Andr\xe9'.encode('utf-8')
'Andr\xc3\xa9'
```

Note that the reason `print 'Andr\xc3\xa9'` gave you the expected result is only because your system's default encoding is UTF-8. For example, on Windows I get:

```
>>> print 'Andr\xc3\xa9'
Andr├⌐
```

As for outputting HTML, it depends on which web framework you use and what encoding you output in the HTML page. Some frameworks (e.g. Django) will convert unicode values to the correct encoding automatically, while others will require you to do so manually.

Comment: I'm currently using Django and the output displayed in the template is AndrÃ©.  Do you know what I should do to make the template display André?

Comment: @Thierry Lam: Django assumes that all non-unicode strings are UTF-8. So in this case you can either use `'Andr\xc3\xa9'` (UTF-8 encoded string) or `u'Andre\xe9'` (unicode string).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> unicode('Andr\xc3\xa9', 'utf-8')
u'Andr\xe9'
>>> print u'Andr\xe9'
André
```

That may answer your question.

EDIT: or see the above answer

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure, but I would guess that different codecs are applied by the print operation. Probably some utf-8 vs. unicode issue.

For HTML, you would need to encode certain characters using the HTML syntax for unicode.
I think that the Python [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) module might be able to help you.

Comment: This is the most rambling, irrelevant, unhelpful answer I have ever read. It's not even wrong, it just doesn't say anything.